# jQuery: Show array element based on first letter of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms

I'm pretty new to javascript, I have an array with an element for each letter of the alphabet:

```
var firstname = [ "Julie", "Jack", "John", ....]
```

I want to populate a specific element in to a tag based on the first letter used in an input field of a form.

For example, if A was the first letter used in the input, it would populate "Julie", B would populate "Jack", C would populate "John" and so on...

Could anyone advise how I could do this in jQuery? Thanks.

Comment: Why not working with numbers? Because if you only use letters you have 26 cases. So what you want is that people type something in a input field and you show the right one?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
var firstname = [ "Julie", "Jack", "John"];

function getElementBasedOnFirstChar(input) {
    var charCode = input.charCodeAt(0);
    
    // Uppercase
    if (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90) {
        return firstname[charCode - 65];
    } 
    // Lowercase
    else if (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122) {
        return firstname[charCode - 97];
    }
    // Non alphabetic characters
    else {
        throw "Illegal start of string";
    }
}

console.log(getElementBasedOnFirstChar("Alfa"));
console.log(getElementBasedOnFirstChar("alfa"));
console.log(getElementBasedOnFirstChar("Bravo"));
console.log(getElementBasedOnFirstChar("Charlie"));
console.log(getElementBasedOnFirstChar("---"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are looking for. But this code gets the value from the input field and checks the array for items starting with the input. I'm just appending it to a div as example.

```js
var firstname = [ "Julie", "Jack", "John", "Peter", "Frank"];

$('#ugh').on('keyup',function(){
//Check if key is a character (a-z | A-Z)
if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90 || event.keyCode >= 97 && event.keyCode <= 122){
  $.each(firstname, function(key, val){ //foreach item in firstname array
   if(val.toLowerCase().match("^" + $('#ugh').val().toLowerCase())){ //text input matches item from array 
    $('#result').append('<p>'+val+'</p>'); //display result, change to whatever you want to do with it
   }
  });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='ugh'/>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: That's close to what I'm after, but I want A to return "Julie", B to return "Jack", C to return "John". As opposed to J returning "Julie", F returning "Frank" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting some thing like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arr = [];
  var firstname = [ "Julie", "Jack", "John"];
  var i = "a";
  $.each(firstname, function(key, value) {
  //  console.log(key, value);
  arr[i] = value;
  var ii =   String.fromCharCode(i.charCodeAt() + 1);
  console.log(ii);
  i = ii;
  console.log(arr);
  });
  alert(arr['a']);
 // console.log(firstname);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/14064/